# "Please let me know."

Tags: phrases, idioms, conversation

Is it okay to answer "Please let me know", short (without "when...", "if...", "what...", etc.)?

Consider for instance

> -- I can check that for you tomorrow morning.
>
> -- Yes, please let me know.

Comment: Okay in what sense? Are you asking if it's a complete sentence or if it's socially acceptable? (The answer is yes to both, but one is uninteresting and the other is off topic.)

Comment: Why would you have a problem with this? Please let me know as soon as you figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a perfectly fine way to respond to that statement. Adding an explicit time frame ("Please let me know as soon as you find out") is permissible and may be clearer, but it's not required.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the extra clause *as soon as you find out*, but it's not really relevant to OP's question, which asks whether it's ok to say *Let me know* without explicitly saying *what*. Which your first sentence covers perfectly, though it's worth pointing out this is only valid if the context makes it crystal clear *what* information is going to be discovered and passed on next day. You can't just walk up to someone in the street and say *Please let me know*.

Answer (score 5):

You can shorten it further:

> Let me know.

This is similar to sentences such as:

> Let me jump.
>
> Let me ride.
>
> Listen.
>
> Go.

Comment: +1, but I made the mistake of reading your examples in rapid sequence and was very bewildered for a moment.

Comment: I'm still confused. Without context I'd assume the likely alternative responses to *I can check...* are either *Yes [do that please]*, or *Don't bother, I can get what I want elsewhere quicker*. Obviously the first applies here, so the short version is just *Yes*. But the *question* asks whether *Let me know* can exist as a standalone utterance. Which of course it can, *provided* the nature of the information being sought is clear from the context.

Comment: @Fumble: Your confusion may be stemming from a mixture of seeking grammatical correctness and the idea that a sentence _means_ something. I can say, "The thingamajig is hooped" and convey virtually no _meaning_ with a more useful context. The sentence still passes a well-formed-grammar test; questioning its meaning (or accuracy) is just a red herring. "I am Abraham Lincoln" is perfectly grammatical even though it would be dead wrong if I spoke it. Likewise, "Let me know." passes the grammar test. Its meaning requires context. The two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @MrHen: Well, I just meant that given enough context, just about *any* really short utterance can be considered grammatically sound. And I'm sure we all agree *Let me know* falls well into that category. As an aside, if I may be so bold, is it fair to say *every* single-word utterance can be valid in the right context? I rather doubt every *two-word* utterance would meet that criteria without straining context to the point of meaninglessness.

Comment: @Fumble: Considering any single word could be considered an answer to a question, you can conceive of a context where it would be appropriate. The issue is whether the sentence can stand on its own; "Let me know" _can_ but doesn't really acquire useful meaning without a context. The examples I offered are other sentences with similar structures. "Let me [verb]" seems okay to me; so does "[verb]." Feel free to look for a verb that doesn't work here; it wouldn't surprise me if one exists.

Comment: @MrHen: Let me deliquesce. Hmm, that doesn't look promising. I think I see what you mean though. Plain *Let* doesn't sound too good either, but as a single word I suppose you'd say it's too short to qualify for grammatic validation as a potentially meaningful utterannce.